# How to target Firefox and IE with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox

There's a slight difference on the layout of my website from webkit browsers to Firefox and Internet Explorer. I need to target Firefox and IE to apply some CSS only in those two browser.

I've tried for Firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    // CSS here
}
```

And I've tried for IE these two solutions:

```
<!--[if IE]><!-->
    // Load specific CSS file here
<!--<![endif]-->

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    // CSS here
}
```

But nothing works. Do I need to do it with Javascript? If so, why can't I target it with CSS or HTML like everyone seems to do?

Comment: IE conditional comments most certainly do work. If you'd explain *why* you think you need to do something special for Firefox, you'd probably get a better answer.

Comment: Also, check here for a broad range of hacks ... http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: This is the website: [link](http://pneuredondo.com/dev/). If you go to the "CONTATO" section, you'll see that the social media icons are not aligned in Firefox and IE, but they are in Chrome and Opera and Safari on MacOS. That's one of the things I want to target for those two browsers. The other is a missing download image/link in the "CAMPANHAS" section.

Comment: Those icons are definitely **not** aligned in Chrome when I look at the page. They've got all sorts of conflicting styles. The best thing to do would be to *fix* your CSS, not attempt browser hacks.

Comment: That's another problem, I can't fix that CSS because it depends on a plugin and it's inside a <i> element which seems to ignore my rules. I've spent the last two days tryin to align them and they are ok at least on my computer's resolution and on another bigger resolution MAC.

Comment: If IE and Firefox are rendering the page one way, and Chrome another, it's probably wiser to look into why Chrome is different. When 2/3 major browsers render one way, the third may be an incorrect implementation of the spec.

Comment: @Pointy Conditional Comments only work in IE versions 9 and prior.

Comment: Please don't *target* specific browsers. Instead, explain what it is you're attempting to do, how Chrome differs from IE/Firefox, and we can work towards a non-hack cross-browser approach instead.

Comment: @JonathanSampson well yes that's true

Comment: I'm trying to align all the social medial circles in the div 'contato-social' in the 'CONTATO' section. Three of them are simple images with links, but three others are from the Shareaholic plugin. I need them all to be aligned and the auto generated code from Shareaholic is messing up with it. With the current CSS they seem to be aligned but only on Chrome and Opera and on 1366x768 resolution. On Firefox and IE at the same resolution, they are 14px above the line of the other 3 non-Shareaholic icons. I want a solution for those 6 icons to be all aligned on every browser.

Comment: Another plugin with the option to share on multiple social media, like the "More Options" in Shareholic ,would also be welcome, if the generated code would be easier to align with the other elements. I'm using the Email and G+ share icons too from Shareaholic, but I believe I can use both without the plugin, it's just the other one to share on multiple social networks that it's a must have.

Answer (score 5):

seems to work for me :

```
// Firefox debug
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #id {rules: argument;}
    ...
}

// IE debug
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .class {rules: arg;}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your browser specific CSS is at the bottom of your CSS files. For ie it should be at the bottom of your head tag in your HTML and for moz make sure it's at the bottom of your CSS file.

Comment: The CSS is at the bottom of the files. That IE part was also at the bottom of the HEAD. Right now for example I have h1 {color: red;} inside the Mozilla identifier and it doesn't work, it doesn't even appear has an overwritten rule when I do "inspect element". Here's the website: [link](http://pneuredondo.com/dev/). You can find H1 tags in "PRODUTOS", the text which is currently white in Firefox and should be red with that rule (that's just an example rule I put online now)

Comment: @DavidMatos What *exactly* do you mwan when you say "it doesn't work"? How can you tell? What do you expect it to look like? What part of the page is wrong?

Comment: @DavidMatos in the case of those `<h1>` tags, the rule *is* working - it's just that you've got another, more-specific rule that's overriding it.

Comment: I see now that the h1 appears when I inspect the element (it wasn't appearing before, I don't know why it did now). But when I try to add the rule I really want, it doesn't appear, which is: .shareaholic-share-buttons-wrapper { margin-top: 14px !important; }. This margin works if I add the rule in the inspector, but when I put it in the CSS nothing happens.

Comment: h1 is less specific than .produtos-text h1, change your moz specific css to .produtos-text h1 { color: red; } and it will work.